# Change property from SAME sibling components on click in Angular 4

Tags: angular

I have a parent component and in that component, 1 other component is included multiple times.

Structure :

parent component :

```
<table>
  <tr class="">
    <td>buttons</td>
  </tr>
  <tr app-myComp></tr>
  <tr app-myComp></tr>
  <tr app-myComp></tr>
  <tr app-myComp></tr>
</table>
```

Child (myComp) component :

```
@Component({
selector: 'tr[app-myComp]',
template: `
                <td><button [style.color]="myColor" (click)="changeColor()">changeColor</button></td>    
            `
})

export class MyComponent {

myColor: string = "blue";

changeColor(): void{
    this.myColor = "red"
}
}
```

When I click on button , text color of button changes from blue to red.

But my question is how can I change text color of **only** clicked button to red and reset all other button's text color to blue?

I know I can get list of MyComponent by @ViewChildren but how can I use them to reset button's text color to blue except clicked one.

I am using angular 4.3.4

codepen link : [Angular 4 app](https://codepen.io/ajinkya_b/project/editor/ZGgGNm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to add a property on the parent component with assigned value to the index of the clicked child. Change its value each time the child is clicked and pass it as a boolean @Input to the child (true if the the property value equal to child's index, false, well, in the reverse condition). In the child component add a condition to check that @Input and set the color only on that condition. And for the child index tracking, add *ngFor instead of repeating the hard coded multiple `<tr app-myComp>`.

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-woyjhy?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)**

**child class:**

```
 ...
 myColor: string;

 @Input()
  set chosen(chosen: boolean) {
    this.myColor = chosen ? "red" : "blue"
  }

 ...
```

**parent view:**

```
<table>
  <tr class="">
    <td>buttons</td>
  </tr>
  <tr app-myComp (click)="chosenTr = i" [chosen]="i == chosenTr" *ngFor="let item of [1,2,3,4]; let i = index"></tr>
</table>
```

**parent class:**

```
  ...
  chosenTr = -1;
  ...
```